# PHP Loop Through Nested JSON Response and Reassemble as Simple Query String for Webhook

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, zapier

I need to send data to a Zapier webhook, as a result, they prefer to use simple query strings.

How can I use PHP to loop to through the following JSON response to reassemble it as a single object? I need to send it as a simple query string to my Zapier webhook.

Specifically, I really want to use "tags" and "tech" data in the Zapier tags input field, which means that I have to send them as individual options otherwise all of the "tags" and "tech" data gets sent as a single tag, rather than individual tags the way you would want them to appear.

As you'll see below some values have arrays, while others have key/value pairs.

```
   {
  "company": {
    "name": "Example Co",
    "legalName": "Example Co LLC",
    "domain": "example.com",
    "domainAliases": [
      "example01.com",
      "example02.com",
      "example03.com"
    ],
    "category": {
      "sector": "Financials",
      "industryGroup": "Diversified Financial Services",
      "industry": "Diversified Financial Services",
      "subIndustry": "Financial Services",
    },
    "tags": [
      "Marketplace",
      "B2C",
      "Financial Services"
    ],
    "foundedYear": null,        
    "tech": [
      "google_analytics",
      "hotjar",
      "outlook",          
    ]
  }
}
```

I want it to look like is the following (notice the _0x numbers being appended where applicable.

```
{
    "company_name": "Example Co",
    "company_legalName": "Example Co LLC",
    "company_domain": "example.com",
    "company_domainAliases_01": "example01.com",
    "company_domainAliases_02": "example02.com",
    "company_domainAliases_03": "example03.com",
    "category_sector": "Financials",
    "category_industryGroup": "Diversified Financial Services",
    "category_industry": "Diversified Financial Services",
    "category_subIndustry": "Financial Services",
    "category_sicCode": null,
    "category_naicsCode": null,
    "tags": "Marketplace",
    "tags": "B2C",
    "tags": "Financial Services",
    "foundedYear": null,
    "tech_01": "google_analytics",
    "tech_02": "hotjar",
    "tech_03": "outlook",   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works good for your scenario. But if you need a generic function, that works with multiple nested arrays, we need to write a recursive function.

```
<?php
$json_contents = file_get_contents('test.json'); //Placed your json in test.json 

$output = array();
$json_array = json_decode($json_contents, true); //Convert json to php array 

foreach ($json_array as $element){  
    foreach ($element as $attribute => $value){ //parse through each attribute 
      if(is_array($value)){   //if value is an array, parse through it and update output array accordingly
          foreach ($value as $a => $v) {
            $output[$attribute.'_'.$a] = $v;
          }
      }
      else{      //if value is not an array, get those elements as they are into $output 
          $output[$attribute] = $value;
      }
  }
}
print_r($output);  //You can convert $output into json using json_encode($output);
print_r($json_array);
```

test.json :

```
{
  "company": {
    "name": "Example Co",
    "legalName": "Example Co LLC",
    "domain": "example.com",
    "domainAliases": [
      "example01.com",
      "example02.com",
      "example03.com"
    ],
    "category": {
      "sector": "Financials",
      "industryGroup": "Diversified Financial Services",
      "industry": "Diversified Financial Services",
      "subIndustry": "Financial Services"
    },
    "tags": [
      "Marketplace",
      "B2C",
      "Financial Services"
    ],
    "foundedYear": null,
    "tech": [
      "google_analytics",
      "hotjar",
      "outlook"
    ]
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Example Co
    [legalName] => Example Co LLC
    [domain] => example.com
    [domainAliases_0] => example01.com
    [domainAliases_1] => example02.com
    [domainAliases_2] => example03.com
    [category_sector] => Financials
    [category_industryGroup] => Diversified Financial Services
    [category_industry] => Diversified Financial Services
    [category_subIndustry] => Financial Services
    [tags_0] => Marketplace
    [tags_1] => B2C
    [tags_2] => Financial Services
    [foundedYear] => 
    [tech_0] => google_analytics
    [tech_1] => hotjar
    [tech_2] => outlook
)
```